# Unity Sound effect playing too many times

Tags: unity, sound

In the class PlayerControl I have this

```
if (Input.GetKey("space")) 
    {           
        soundManager.PlayBleep();
        sword.SetActive(true);
    }
```

In my soundmanager I have this

```
   public void PlayBleep()
{
    if (!audio.isPlaying) {
        audio.PlayOneShot(SwordWhip2);          
    }   
}
```

At the moment I am getting the sound like 10 times each time I press space creating horrible soundeffects. How could I get it not to play until the sound has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlayOneShot` does not alter `isPlaying`. See [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/123772/playoneshot-returns-false-for-isplaying.html). So `isPlaying` will always be false.

A simple fix is to change your input to only trigger once. Instead of `Input.GetKey("space")` you can use `Input.GetKeyDown("space")`.

You can alternatively add your own flag for when the weapon is active. This additional flag would likely be useful for the animation and other time delays to keep the sword from swinging too fast.

Comment: Yeah thats what i did, using a flag. So i guess its a bug?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: You could also use a coroutine. Basically at the start of the coroutine set a local bool (playingSound) to true, then use play one shot, do a yield return wait sound.length, and finally set your bool back to false. This way you only trigger the coroutine once and it will just ignore all other play one shot calls.